# What is the cost of the volatile keyword in a multiprocessor system?

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile

we're running into performance issues, and one potential culprit is a centralized use of a volatile singleton. the specific code is of the form

```
class foo {
  static volatile instance;
  static object l = new object();

  public static foo Instance {
    if (instance == null)
      lock(l) {
        if (instance == null)
          instance = new foo();
      }

    return foo();
  }
}
```

this is running on an 8-way box, and we're seeing context switching to the tune of 500,000 per second. typical system resources are fine - 25% cpu util, 25% memory util, low IO, no paging, etc.

does using a volatile field induce a memory barrier or any kind of cpu cache reload? or does it just go after main memory every time, for that field only?

Comment: I'm not sure why this needs to be a volatile, as you're not changing the reference.

Comment: i'm not either - this is someone's code i'm debugging. my main question, though, is could the use of volatile here cause contention issues on a multi-core x86 box

Comment: While this is an *old* question, why does this "DCL-style" code return a *new instance* in the non-null case? Doesn't that inherently *break* the guarantee it's a singleton?

Comment: @user2864740 it works because volatile is roughly the equivalent of lock, so you're basically doing lock twice.

Comment: @kolosy The above comment was wrt: why is `return foo();` returned *instead of* `return instance;` (where instance != null per the DCL pattern)? That will return a *new* foo each time.

Comment: @kolosy Also, I disagree to equating volatile to lock.. while lock enforces a memory fence, there are *important differences* that such that the operations should generally not be considered "roughly equivalent". For example, removing the `lock` above would *result in invalid code*, even with `volatile`. And removing the `volatile` above would *result in invalid code* (assuming DCL is *actually used* and a singleton is returned, see previous comment), even with the `lock`.

Comment: @user2864740 oh that seems like an 8 year old typo that you're welcome to fix. w/r/t the equivalence of volatile and lock, in this context the effect is the same. it enforces a memory barrier, has acquire/release semantics, and enforces execution order. yes, they do different things and have differences, but in this context they do the same thing.

Comment: @kolosy :D Anyway - `lock` *only* establishes the memory barrier *as / if* it is entered. This is why in DCL it is required that the field is `volatile` to ensure thread-safety (it is possible that execution from other threads never enters the lock and it is the outside code that is subject to re-ordering). The use of `volatile` is not for the variable access *inside* the lock. Moving the `return instance;` (*cough*) inside the `lock` avoids the issue but it then negates any [supposed] benefits of DCL as the lock is "always entered".

Comment: @kolosy As a random note: ReSharper will actively warn about this DCL pattern without the use of `volatile`. Also, unlike with much easier-to-prove-invalid code, such DCL / singleton design (especially on x86) have a very limited window of opportunity in which unexpected behavior can be observed and/or affect execution .. this still doesn't mean it has guaranteed thread-safety (outside of a specific implementation and execution environment) unless lock *and* volatile are used together.

Comment: @user2864740 please don't take this post as an endorsement of the DCL anti-pattern. It's clearly wrong, but wasn't what I was looking at with this question. In that context, then, volatile and lock accomplish the same thing, and, in fact, cost more together than they otherwise would, as it invokes 2 memory barriers in the null case instead of 1, and 1 always.

Comment: @kolosy DCL is 'fine' if written correctly, although there are often simpler approaches. I've not posted any answer as correctness is tangential to the "performance cost" or "if a lock implies a memory fence" - however, there is a Thread-Safe Way to write a DCL and a Questionable Way. And yes, *I just had to deal with [threading-unsafe DCL] code which failed on production systems* due to invalid thread-safety in a DCL / initialize-once pattern related to not using `volatile`; and why I even stumbled back here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lock` does induce a memory barrier, so if you are always accessing instance in a lock you don't need the volatile.

According to [this site](http://dotnet.org.za/markn/archive/2008/10/21/net-memory-model-bytecode-reordering.aspx):

> The C# volatile keyword implements acquire and release semantics, which implies a read memory barrier on read and a write memory barrier on write.

Comment: no - take a look at the code. theoretically, lock will only occur once, as after that the volatile variable will be set, and the outer check will pass.

Comment: Vance Morrison also covers DCL in this MSDN article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx

Answer (score 3):

One thing volatile will not do is cause a context switch.  If you're seeing 500,000 context switches per second, it means that your threads are blocking on something and volatile is *not* the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the singleton takes a bad rap for just about everything :)

This isn't my domain of expertise, but as far as I know there's nothing special about volatile other than the compiler/run-time NOT re-ordering read/writes (to the variable) for optimization purposes.

Edit:  I stand corrected.  Not only does volatile introduce memory barriers, but what goes on (and incidentally,  performance) depends largely on the particular CPU involved.
See http://dotnetframeworkplanet.blogspot.com/2008/11/volatile-field-and-memory-barrier-look.html

This is why you still need the lock.

Questions which may/may not have been answered already:

1. What is your singleton instance actually doing?  Maybe the instance code needs to be refactored...
2. What's the thread count of the running process?  An 8 way box won't help you if you have an abnormally high thread count.
3. If it's higher than expected, why?
4. What else is running on the system?
5. Is the performance issue consistent?

Comment: 1. not much. it's a container for some data that needs to be globally available
2. thread count is adequate. context switching/second is ridiculously high. 500,000/s
3. good question.
4. nothing.
5. yes

Answer (score 0):

In your example here, volatile should  not be the subject of any "slowdown".
The lock() however, can involve huge roundtrips to the kernel, especially if there's a lot of  contention for the lock.

There is really no need to lock your singleton in this case, you could just
do

```
class Foo {
  static Foo instance = new Foo();
  public static Foo FooInstance() {
    return instance ;
  }
}
```

Ofcourse, if 'instance ' is used in a lot of different threads, you'd still have to lock() anything that alters that Foo, unless all methods/properties of Foo is readonly.
e.g.

```
 class Foo {
      static Foo instance = new Foo();
      object l = new object();
      int doesntChange = 42;
      int canChange = 123;
      public static Foo FooInstance() {
        return instance ;
      }
      public void Update(int newVal) {
         lock(l) { // you'll get a lot of trouble without this lock if several threads accesses the same FOO. Atleast if they later on read that variable 
            canChange = newVal;
         }

      public int GetFixedVal() {
         return doesntChange; //no need for a lock. the doesntChange is effectivly read only
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need for the use of volatile for a singleton, as you're setting it exactly once - and locking the code the sets it. See [Jon Skeet's article on singletons](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) for more info.

Comment: A DCL without a memory barrier on the read is "Third version - attempted (and failed) thread-safety using double-check locking .. *Without any memory barriers, it's broken in the ECMA CLI specification too.*". The OPs code is odd in that it can return *multiple* foo's (instead of returning `instance`, which represents a *different issue*) .. this old post (2006) makes no indication that a DCL *without memory guards* is safe for singletons (again, a bug in the code..?)

Comment: http://benbowen.blog/post/cmmics_iii/ - see note on ".Net memory model 2.0" 'guarantees'.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, Yes it creates a memory barrier (flushes everything and goes to main memory, not just that single variable), but No it will not be the cause of context switching.

Also, as others have mentioned, I don't believe volatile is necessary here.

Comment: `volatile` is necessary to *guarantee* thread-safety (it is not the only option, but is one that is required in the basic DCL singleton pattern). It prevents re-ordering (and ensures a "non-stale" read) when the code *does not* acquire the lock: if the code *always* entered the lock there would be no benefit of `volatile`.

Comment: I agree with your statement, but in the above example a lock is being used which includes memory barriers and prevents reordering. Or am I confusing something?